# Does .loc in Python Pandas make inplace change on the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I was working on a dataframe like below:

df:

```
Site   Visits   Temp   Type
KFC    511      74     Food
KFC    565      77     Food
KFC    498      72     Food
K&G    300      75     Gas
K&G    255      71     Gas
```

I wanted to change 'Type' column into 0-1 variable so I could use df.corr() to check the correlation.

I tried two ways, one was to make a dictionary and make a new column:

```
dict = {'Food':1, 'Gas':0}
df['BinaryType'] = df['Type'].map(dict)
```

I was then able to use `df.corr()` to check correlation between 'Visits' and 'BinaryType'. Since 'Type' column contains strings, df.corr() would not show correlation between 'Visits' and 'Type'.

Second way was to use .loc:

```
df.loc[df['Type']=='Food','Type'] = 1
df.loc[df['Type']!=1,'Type'] = 0
```

Then I checked df in console, it was like below and it seemed an inplace change was made. I also checked the data type using `df['Type'][0]` and it read 1(I suppose it's integer):

```
Site   Visits   Temp   Type
KFC    511      74     1
KFC    565      77     1
KFC    498      72     1
K&G    300      75     0
K&G    255      71     0
```

Here however, `df.corr()` would not show correlation between 'Visits' and 'Type'! It was as if this column hadn't been changed.

You can use the code below to reproduce:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Site': {0: 'KFC', 1: 'KFC', 2: 'KFC', 3: 'K&G', 4:'K&G'},
    'Visits': {0: 511, 1: 565, 2: 498, 3: 300, 4:255},
    'Temp': {0: 74, 1: 77, 2: 72, 3: 75, 4:71},
    'Type': {0: 'Food', 1: 'Food', 2: 'Food', 3: 'Gas', 4:'Gas'}})
# 1
dict = {'Food':1, 'Gas':0}
df['BinaryType'] = df['Type'].map(dict)
df.corr()
del df['BinaryType']

# 2
df.loc[df['Type']=='Food','Type'] = 1
df.loc[df['Type']!=1,'Type'] = 0
df.corr()
```

Any idea on how Pandas .loc works on the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd method doesn't actually change the `dtype` of the series even though the values are all ints. You can see that by doing `df.dtypes` which would show the `Type` column is still of `object` dtype

You need to explicitly cast them to int using an `.astype(int)`

OR

use `df['Type'] = np.where(df['Type'] == 'Food', 1, 0)`

running `df.corr()` after that gives

```py
In [22]: df.corr()
Out[22]:
          Visits      Temp      Type
Visits  1.000000  0.498462  0.976714
Temp    0.498462  1.000000  0.305888
Type    0.976714  0.305888  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

As your first method is working, you can just use:

```
dict = {'Food':1, 'Gas':0}
df['Type'] = df['Type'].map(dict)
```